# problem with fetching the toOptionArray() values

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, system.xml

In my module I'm fetching the toOptionArray() values but it's displaying empty.

**multiselect dropdown should be below format.**

```
Major
    Test 1
    Test 2
Major 2
    Test 3
    Test 4
```

**my code is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <msmultiflat translate="label" module="shipping">
                    <label>Multiple Flat rates </label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sort_order>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>

                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Allowed Methods</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>Easylife_Shippings_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Custom_Source_Method</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                        <price1 translate="label">
                            <label>• Price (0.00)</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </price1>
                        <details1 translate="label">
                            <label>• Details</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </details1>
                        <type1 translate="label">
                            <label>• Type</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_flatrate</source_model>
                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </type1>
                        <min_shipping1 translate="label">
                            <label>• Minimum order amount</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </min_shipping1>
                        <max_shipping1 translate="label">
                            <label>• Maximum order amount</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>9</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </max_shipping1>
                        <sallowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to applicable countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>44</sort_order>
                            <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sallowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Specific countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <showmethod translate="label">
                            <label>Show method if not applicable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>92</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </showmethod>
                        <specificerrmsg translate="label">
                            <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificerrmsg>
                    </fields>
                </msmultiflat>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

//

```
class Easylife_Shippings_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Custom_Source_Method
{

     public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        array(
        'label' => 'Major',
        'value' => array(
            array('value' => 'test1', 'label' => 'Test 1'),
            array('value' => 'test2', 'label' => 'Test 2')
        )
    ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Minor',
            'value' => array(
                array('value' => 'test1', 'label' => 'Test 1'),
                array('value' => 'test2', 'label' => 'Test 2')
            )
        )
    );

}

}
```

my logs created below formate.

```
2014-07-01T09:07:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Major
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => test1
                    [label] => Test 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => test2
                    [label] => Test 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Major1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => test3
                    [label] => Test 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => test4
                    [label] => Test 4
                )

        )

)
```

can you suggest me where I went wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the return format of the function `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true)`, which is used for getting the store information in a multiselect. It returns the array in the following format:

```
// For single level item
array(
    'label' => Your Label,
    'value' => your value
)
// For multi level item
array(
    'label' => Your Label,
    'value' => array(
         array(
             'label' => Your Next Level Label,
             'value' => Your Next level value
         )
    )
)
```

With this in mind your array should look as follows:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Major',
            'value' => array(
                array('value' => 'test1', 'label' => 'Test 1'),
                array('value' => 'test2', 'label' => 'Test 2')
            )
        ),
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'label' => 'major2',
            'value' => array(
                array('value' => 'test3', 'label' => 'Test 3'),
                array('value' => 'test4', 'label' => 'Test 4')
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: multiselect control have no data it's empty.

Comment: What is your system.xml entry?

Comment: see my thread updated.

Comment: @ManojKumar so the multiselect is empty but if you log in the function you are getting log entries

Comment: Yes david manners.

Comment: @ManojKumar if the same source model is not being used somewhere else on the page then try simply returning a single element in the array to check if anything else is causing an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15467/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-david-manners).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $arr = array(
            array(  
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Major',
                         array('value' => 'test1', 'label' => 'Test 1'),
                         array('value' => 'test2', 'label' => 'Test 2')
                    )
            ),    
            array(
                    array(
                            'label' => 'major2',
                            array('value' => 'test3', 'label' => 'Test 3'),
                            array('value' => 'test4', 'label' => 'Test 4')
                    )
            )

        );
     Mage::log($arr);
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: ,No results. Displayed empty.

Comment: your log is empty ?

Comment: log is created but in adminpanel multiselect control have no data.

Comment: In your question, you just specified how to get described format using that function. I think changes that I showed you will output the exact output that you would need. You can see output in your log. From where you are trying to get the $arr ?